# what is the minimum possible number of teams that won at least one event?

Tags: combinatorics

$7$ teams compete in a track competition. If there are $20$
events in the competition, no event ends in a tie, and no
team wins more than 3 events, what is the minimum
possible number of teams that won at least one event?

---

I do not have idea how to solve it,some hints will help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose, there is a team that won no event. The other $6$ teams could have won at most $18$ events. This is a contradiction. So, the correct answer is $7$ (all).

Answer (score 4):

HINT: If $6$ teams win the maximum of $3$ events each, that accounts for $18$ of the $20$ events. What can you now say about the seventh team?